# Images for Assembler, Interpreter and Compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, image, interpreter, assembly, language-concepts

I got an assignment to make hand-drawn posters of

- Assembler
- Interpreter
- Compiler

I googled for images of above three but not able to get some exact images which can define the above three properly. Can anyone share some image links which will give an idea about what is Assembler, Interpreter and compiler in computers.

Thanks

Comment: An image is (usually) a metaphor; the concepts cited are pretty technical. I doubt you'll find  an "exact image" that can define them *properly*...

Comment: I just want to demonstrate it, nothing in-depth needed, bu a basic overview in the form of image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you:

- [Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), the image is pretty simple and takes the primordial concept.
- [Interpreter](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~rivero/doc/2008-2009-q2/interpreters.4up.pdf), in this presentation you'll get various examples with different levels of detail.
- [Assembler](http://www.davidsalomon.name/assem.advertis/asl.pdf), this book its a comprehensive material on ASM, here figure 1 can help you (as well as figure 2 and 3 that explain Two-pass assemblers and One-pass assemblers, respectively)

Comment: Thanks, its perfect, this what I want. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could draw diagrams that indicate the set of input and outputs for each component. For example, an assembler takes assembly language code as input and produces binary object code as output.